# Why does Virtual Box freeze on "Starting Windows" screen on macOS Catalina 10.15.7?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have macOS Catalina 10.15 and I installed VirtualBox v7.0 to run Windows 7 x64 (and windows10 x64). When I boots it hangs at "Starting Windows" screen. Screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Mac OS Catalina has some compatibilty issues with Virtual Box version 7.x.x. Because I have an old MacBook Pro thet only supports Mac OS Catalina but none of newer I can not upgrade to newer Mac OS versions like ventura which is the newest as I write this post. I have uninstalled Virtual Box v 7.x.x then installed Virtual Box verison 1.6.50. After that I have installed the extension pack suitable with this version. Thats it. No more problems. Here ist he link you can find the old 1.6.50 version and the releted extension pack.
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_1
Hope this solves your problem too.